# Variable not being defined in object

Tags: java, string, variables, object

I created a student class and I need to use the students first name followed by their code (first student is 1000, nxt is 1001) to create a loginId Using
 first letter of name + last name (or if last name is longer than 4 letters just 4 letters of the last name) + ending digits of their code
for example John Baker would be, jbake00

```
    public class Student
    {
//Instance variables
private double coursecount = 0;
private static int lastAssignedNumber = 1000;
private double credit;
private String course;
//Variables
public String name;     
public String address;
public String loginId = "";
public int accountNumber;
public double gpa;

//Constructs new student
public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accountNumber = lastAssignedNumber;
    lastAssignedNumber++;
            setloginid();//edited this one in
}

public void setloginId()        {
    int position = this.name.indexOf(' ');
    String first_name = this.name.substring(0,1);
    String last_name = this.name.substring(position + 1);
    if(last_name.length() >= 4) 
        last_name = last_name.substring(0,4);
    first_name = first_name.toLowerCase();
    last_name = last_name.toLowerCase();
    String digit_word = new Integer(accountNumber).toString();
    String digit_short = digit_word.substring(2);
    loginId += first_name + last_name + digit_short;
        this.loginId = loginId;
}
```

The problem i have here is that loginId isn't being saved into the global variable why is that.

Comment: what do you mean it isnt saved? you arent able to see the value of loginId when you try to access it from another method? (provided the setloginId() runs before that method where you are trying to get this value)

Comment: Where are you calling `setloginId()`?

Comment: Yes while i try to access loginId from another method i just get an empty string.

sorry im new at this im just creating that constructor to try to set the loginId as a value.

Comment: *"im just creating that constructor to try to set the `loginId` as a value"* Then you should call the method `setloginId()` in the constructor.

Comment: would this be proper programing? As in style wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `setloginId()` method somewhere. From your comments, you seem to want to do it in the constructor:

> im just creating that constructor to try to set the loginId as a value

As follows:

```
public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accountNumber = lastAssignedNumber;
    lastAssignedNumber++;
    setloginId(); //need to call this
}
```

You may also want to privatize your `setloginId()` method as it's not necessary to expose it:

```
private void setloginId() {
```

Also a minor change, you can change:

```
    loginId += first_name + last_name + digit_short;
    this.loginId = loginId;
```

to:

```
    this.loginId = first_name + last_name + digit_short;
```

It's not necessary to do `+=` as it is going to append to the existing string, which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the method setLoginID from the constructor of your object. And you can make the method a private method, i don't think there is any use in accessing it from anywhere else than from your constructor